# ngbTooltip - Cancel tooltip appearance during delay

Tags: javascript, angular, tooltip, ng-bootstrap

I use ngbTooltip on many elements in my application.

Each tooltip is initialized as follows directly in the HTML code

```html
  <div
    ngbTooltip="my tooltip"
    container="body"
    placement="left"
    openDelay="1000"
    triggers="hover"
    (click)="doSomething()"
  >
    click me !
  </div>
```

Everything works fine, unless the user clicks on the HTML element **before the specified delay has elapsed.**

In this case, the GUI is partially modified and the element used to trigger the tooltip is no longer displayed but after the delay, **the tooltip is still displayed** in the top left corner of the screen.

How to cancel the appearance of the tooltip once the button has been clicked or when the triggering element is no longer displayed  ?

My versions are :
ng-bootstrap:16.0.0 and angular: 17.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after trying just about everything, I came across [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tirenu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) using **ngx-bootstrap tooltip**, which explains and simply solves my problem by using this attribute:

```html
triggers="mouseenter:click mouseenter:mouseleave"
```

I tried to replicate it with ng-bootstrap but couldn't.

So I decided to replace all my tooltips and use **ngx-bootstrap** instead.